# how to show only the data of the user that is logged in (Django)

Tags: django, database, new-operator

So it shows data like all objects but now I only want to show the specific data of each user
this is my views.py:

```
def Campos(request):
    dados = Cultivo.objects.all().order_by('name')    
    return render(request,'Agrefarm/Campos.html', {'dados':dados})
```

and this is my models.py

```
class Cultivo(models.Model):
    Dono = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    descrição = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Arvores = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def curto(self):
    return self.descrição[:15]
```

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Copy the code into the post in a code block. It is easier for people to work with your code when it is actually written into the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll want to do something like this:

```
dados = Cultivo.objects.filter(Dono = request.user)
```

I believe that'll work for you.

Comment: It works but when I log out I get another error: "'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable" ? maybe because a user is not logged in?

Comment: You are probably correct.  You'll want to read up on Django's built in user authentication mechanism.  It's not extremely difficult to use as the documentation on it is pretty good.  Let me know if you run into any issues with it.